# Change hyperlink (href) dynamically based on content of H2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, getelementbyid

I'm currently helping a large affiliate website to replace their links dynamically.

They want to use the contents of the H2 tags following their images with the class name `wp-block-image`.

This is what the code looks like:

`<h2 id="somebookname">Name of some book</h2>`

**Link: https://www.somesite.com/search-suggestion/**

**Intended result: https://www.somesite.com/search-suggestion/Name of Some Book** (yes, the spaces in final URL are OK!)

We want to add 'Name of some book' (content of H2) as a suffix to the link above. Any help would be appreciated.

Given that the h2 id changes, **we are looking to target every H2 following the .wp-block-image class.**

Willing to use either jQuery or Javascript to achieve this.

Example:

`<div class="wp-block-image"></div>`

`<h2 id="somebookname">Name of some book</h2>`

We want to change this div on pageview:

`<div class="searchsuggestion">URL: https://www.somesite.com/search-suggestion/</div>`

To become:

`<div class="searchsuggestion">URL: https://www.somesite.com/search-suggestion/Name of some book</div>`

Comment: Please show us your attempt, and a [mre]!

Comment: These requirements were quite unclear . The DOM structure is not at all defined. What does this even mean: "every H2 following the .wp-block-image class.". Show example html. And where are the links? Do they exist or should they be appended somewhere?

Comment: @oligofren I just added an example above.

If the URL was literally present on the page in a div and we wanted to change the suffix the example should show you. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense... but there are multiple h2s and just a single div on the page?

Comment: No there are 3 images on the page most often and 1 h2 below every image. Also a div is available under every image. We want to change the search string in that div dynamically with the contents of H2.

Comment: When you write "URL: https://www.somesite.com/search-suggestion/Name of some book" you don't really want the link as plain text, right? In my answer, I created actual links, but I can of course produce the "URL: ..." form.

Answer (score 0):

Tjena. This answer is based on your explanation of the DOM structure, reproduced below in my runnable snippet. If it should not match 100%, just update the selector accordingly.

```js
const imageBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".wp-block-image");

imageBlocks.forEach((block) => {
  const header = block.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];
  const link = block.querySelector(".searchsuggestion a");
  link.href += header.innerText;
});
```

```html
<div class="wp-block-image">
   <h2 id="book-a">Book of Mormon</h2>
   <div class="searchsuggestion">
    <a href="https://www.somesite.com/search-suggestion/">Klicka mig!</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

This answer is made per your question, and is not what I would recommend. The real answer is to change the rendered HTML on the backend side, of course, but I assume you do not have access to it.